# Using Sqoop1 with SAP HANA using a table name that contains forward slash '/' causes error

Tags: sqoop, hana

Trying to import data from SAP HANA using table that contains a forward slash '/'. Not sure if escaping the '/' will work.

My connection attempt:

```
sqoop import –connect jdbc:sap://mysaphost:30015 --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver --username xxxxxx --password xxxx --table xxx./xxx/xxx
```

Produces the following error:

> 2016-05-20 13:12:23,098 ERROR - [main:] ~ Error executing statement: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "/": line 1 col 24 (at pos 24) (SqlManager:43)
>
> com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "/": line 1 col 24 (at pos 24)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to latest version of JDBC driver for SAP Hana.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use object names with slashes (or other special characters) you need to enclose them into double quotation marks (").

As you seem to use a command line interface and want to pass the table name as an argument, you most likely have to escape those quotation.

Try something like

```
sqoop import –connect jdbc:sap://mysaphost:30015 --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver 
--username xxxxxx --password xxxx --table \"xxx./xxx/xxx\"
```

(still just one line!) and see how that goes.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Unfortunately using the \" before and after the table name produces the same error.

Comment: Hmm... Ok, I don't have a sqoop to test with. But go and try without the backslahes in front of the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, But maybe you can just try to enclose table name with double quotations (")

```
sqoop import –connect jdbc:sap://mysaphost:30015 --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver --username xxxxxx --password xxxx --table xxx."/xxx/xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like --table "XXX".\" XYZ\"