# sqoop issue while importing data from SAP HANA

Tags: sqoop, hana

We are currently we are moving data from SAP HANA to Hadoop using sqoop.
SAP HANA tables uses '' character in table name and column names. our reqular sqoop command is working, but it is failing when I use "Split by". Can any one pls help.

code:

```
/usr/hdp/sqoop/bin/sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:sap://***-***.**.*****.com:30015" \
--username DFIT_SUPP_USR --password **** \
--driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver \
--query  "select '\"/BA1/C55LGENT/\"' FROM \"_SYS_BIC\".\"sap.fs.frdp.300.RDL/BV_RDL_ZAFI______Z_SLPD\" where \$CONDITIONS and (\"/BA1/C55LGENT\") IN  ('0000000671','0000000615') and (\"/BA1/C55LGENT\" != '0000000022') AND (\"/BIC/ZCINTEIND\" ='01') AND (\"/BA1/IGL_ACCOUNT\") IN ( '0000401077', '0000401035') AND (\"/BA1/C55POSTD\">= '20170101'   AND \"/BA1/C55POSTD\" <='20170101')"  \
--target-dir /user/arekapalli/pfit_export_test12 \
--delete-target-dir \
--split-by //BA1//C55LGENT// \
-m 10
```

Below is the error we got..

> Caused by: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 12): sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "/": line 1 col 12 (at pos 12)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356777/using-sqoop1-with-sap-hana-using-a-table-name-that-contains-forward-slash-ca/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633666/sqoop-import-to-hive-from-hana-with-special-characters-in-table-name)? Two different solutions. Searched a bit, no good answer anywhere, even the [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1722) was issued which is unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is probably here

```
--query  "select '\"/BA1/C55LGENT/\"' FROM \"_SYS_BIC\".\"sap.fs.frdp.300.RDL/BV_RDL_ZAFI______Z_SLPD\" where \$CONDITIONS and (\"/BA1/C55LGENT\") IN  ('0000000671','0000000615') and (\"/BA1/C55LGENT\" != '0000000022') AND (\"/BIC/ZCINTEIND\" ='01') AND (\"/BA1/IGL_ACCOUNT\") IN ( '0000401077', '0000401035') AND (\"/BA1/C55POSTD\">= '20170101'   AND \"/BA1/C55POSTD\" <='20170101')"  \
```

you are assuming that the "\" is a escape character used from the terminal, that is probabliy wrong.  try the following

```
--query  'select "/BA1/C55LGENT/" FROM "_SYS_BIC"."sap.fs.frdp.300.RDL/BV_RDL_ZAFI______Z_SLPD" where \$CONDITIONS and ("/BA1/C55LGENT") IN  ("0000000671","0000000615") and ("/BA1/C55LGENT" != "0000000022") AND ("/BIC/ZCINTEIND" ="01") AND ("/BA1/IGL_ACCOUNT") IN ( "0000401077", "0000401035") AND ("/BA1/C55POSTD">= "20170101"   AND "/BA1/C55POSTD" <="20170101")'  \
```

I am not a sap user, so maybe could be something wrong with the query, anyway you can see that I removed all your ' from the query and I used the as delimiter of the query